# LDAP User switches to local user mid session

Tags: ldap, login

So, what's happening is I have an LDAP server and two clients:

- LDAP Server = Ubuntu 16.04 Headless
- Client 1 = Ubuntu Gnome 16.04
- Client 2 = Ubuntu 16.04 (XFCE, Gnome & Unity)

I have it all configured so both clients properly connect and authenticate with the LDAP server. However, during each session on either client, if I try and run something that requires a password prompt (ex: Clicking Unlock on the "Users" window to make changes) all of the sudden, the session is being run as the local admin user as opposed to the LDAP user. To get it to revert back to the LDAP user, typically I have to log out, but a reboot is more frequently required.

When I first login:

[image]

After I get password prompt:

[image]

I'm trying to understand what's causing the system to switch to the local user and no longer use the LDAP user.

So, the big question is, what's causing the LDAP user session to "end" and then migrate itself over to the local user?

Comment: What happens if you click Lock after Unlocking?

Comment: As of right now, the user stays as the local account and doens't sync back up it seem to the LDAP user until reboot. Logging out doesn't seem to fix it.